# Смена условия в переменной при запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

В общем, мне нужно сделать так.  
Если при JOIN ничего нет, то подсунуть ему другое условие JOIN, но с сохранением в ту же переменную. Как это можно сделать?

```
SELECT
     profile_orders.id id,
     user_id,
     user_name,
     DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') `date`,
     status,
     `from`,
     `where`,
     model_plane,
     flight_hours,
     price,
     passengers,
     a1.name_rus name_rus_from,
     a1.name_eng name_eng_from,
     a2.name_rus name_rus_where,
     a2.name_eng name_eng_where,
     a1.city_rus city_rus_from,
     a1.city_eng city_eng_from,
     a2.city_rus city_rus_where,
     a2.city_eng city_eng_where,
     a1.country_rus country_rus_from,
     a1.country_eng country_eng_from,
     a2.country_rus country_rus_where,
     a2.country_eng country_eng_where,
     bort.model_vts model_vts,
     bort.model_id model_id,
     bort.airport_icao airport_icao

    FROM profile_orders
    JOIN calc_airport a1 ON a1.icao_code = profile_orders.`from`
    JOIN calc_airport a2 ON a2.icao_code = profile_orders.`where`

    (JOIN airplanes_table bort ON bort.bort_number = profile_orders.model_plane) 
    OR (JOIN airplanes_table2 bort ON bort3.bort_number = profile_orders1.model_plane)

    WHERE user_id = 1
```

Подумал, как нибудь так, но эта конструкция не валидна.

```
    (JOIN airplanes_table bort ON bort.bort_number = profile_orders.model_plane) 
    OR (JOIN airplanes_table2 bort ON bort3.bort_number = profile_orders1.model_plane)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте два запроса и объедините их UNION'ом.